# triggering a jquery's ready() from another webpage's jquery's ready()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, ajax-request

I could not get the child's ajax result in parent page..the child's component does not get displayed in parent page.My guess is that the child's ready function is not getting triggered.I am not sure of why?any help would be much appreciated.
Sample call:

```
 //parent page contains this function
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $('#a').click(function()
  {
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url : "child_ajax.php",                     
            data:{},
            success : function(result){
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#result_div').html(result);
                }, 100);
            }
  });
 });
 });
 <div id="result_div"></div>
 <div id="a">click</div>

//child_ajax.php
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   alert('welcome');
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "child2_ajax.php",                    
    data:{},
    success : function(result){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#result_div_child').html(result);
    }, 100);
    }
  });
      });
  <div id="result_div_child"><div>
```

Comment: It's not working because there is only one `document` object in the page. It cannot be "ready" twice.
If your `child_ajax` page is only accessible with AJAX, you should simply remove the `$(document).ready` event, and execute your code directly.

Comment: same functionality works if i make the child component to be triggered via a button's click event. But when i try to trigger the child component via parent's ready() it doesn't.

Comment: This is because your child page is not yet loaded when the parent page is ready. And `$(document).ready` happens only once. Have you tried to remove the `$(document).ready` on the child page ?

Comment: child's ready() is mandatory since it builds another component via Jquery! is there a way i can fix this ?

Comment: thanks a lot..It is working now after i removed the ready function from child page..